# Can't access build parameters in excute shell in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to call a python script through an execute shell step in a Jenkins parametrized build. The problem is I need to pass the build parameters to the python script which doesn't happen. Here is how I call the python script in execute shell:

```
python2.7 C:\test\my_script.py  -m $module
```

`$module` is passed as an empty string.

I've tried in Execute Windows batch command with `%module%` and it worked fine. 
But I need to run it on an excute shell not a windows batch command.

Comment: For testing you can call "env" in your Jenkins shell code to see all variables.

Comment: What is your console output? If you're calling "execute shell", are you using cygwin? In that case, your path to the script is wrong. If you're using some other shell, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running on Windows ("**C:\test\my_script.py ...**"), so "Execute shell" will not work properly.

Should either use **Execute Windows batch command** or move your job to a Unix/Linux machine (can use a Jenkins-Agent for that).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
python2.7 C:\test\my_script.py  -m $MODULE
```

From the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)

> Note that because of the case sensitivity difference of environment
>   variables in Windows and Unix, all the environment variables added by
>   parameters **are in upper case**.

Hence please try using `$MODULE` instead of `$module`